# Python: BeautifulSoup extract all the heading text from div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://aicd.companydirectors.com.au/events/events-calendar')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")


event_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8")

first_event = event_containers[0]  
print(first_event.h3.text)
```

By using this code i'm able  to extract the event name,I'm trying for a way to loop and extract all the event names and dates ? and also i'm trying to extract the location information which is visable after clicking on readmore link

Comment: ```for movie in movie_containers:```

Comment: Will try this, Just for a FYI i just replaced movie with event, So that it can be better understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event_containers` is a `bs4.element.ResultSet` object, which is basically a list of `Tag` objects.
Just loop over the tags in `event_containers` and select `h3` for the title, `div.date` for the date and `a` for the URL, example:

```
for tag in event_containers:
    print(tag.h3.text)
    print(tag.select_one('div.date').text)
    print(tag.a['href'])
```

Now, for the location information you'll have to visit each URL and collect the text in `div.date`.
Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://aicd.companydirectors.com.au/events/events-calendar')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
event_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8")
base_url = 'http://aicd.companydirectors.com.au'

for tag in event_containers:
    link = base_url + tag.a['href']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text,"lxml")
    location = ', '.join(list(soup.select_one('div.event-add').stripped_strings)[1:-1])
    print('Title:', tag.h3.text)
    print('Date:', tag.select_one('div.date').text)
    print('Link:', link)
    print('Location:', location)
```

Comment: This is great, Can you also please help me finding location information and also help me understand the method?

Comment: I tried to explain my answer, if you have a specific question please ask. About the location info, do you need the link or the text?

Comment: I'm looking for location text and event hyperlink

Comment: For the text you'll have to send an extra request, i'll update my code.

Comment: @ t.m.adam Thanks for helpinp out me with location, This is great and I learened few basics from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all the events and dates you are after:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://aicd.companydirectors.com.au/events/events-calendar')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_='lead'):
    date = item.find_previous_sibling().text.split(" |")[0]
    print(item.text,date)
```

Comment: @ Shahin This is great, Can you also please help me finding location information and also help me understand the method?

Comment: If you want to get related information attached to each `date` then take this portion out `.split(" |")[0]`.

Comment: To get the location info you need to parse the link connected to `read more` option and then creating another http requests you can reach there. However, that is for another post. As for the understanding of the method concern, my python guru sir t.m.adam has provided you one. Thanks.